# Basic sql insert statement

Tags: mysql, sql, database, insert

I've looked through so many past questions, and I'm still struggling!

```
<?php

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","***","***") or die ("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("****");

$sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (id, first_name, last_name, email) VALUES (' ',       
'$_POST[first_name], $_POST[last_name], $_POST[email]')") or die ('Error updating   
database: '.mysql_error());

?>
```

Every time, I'm getting this error: 
Error updating database: `Column count doesn't match value count at row 1`

This is the form it's receiving information from:

```
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
        Firstname: <input type="text" name="first_name">
        Lastname: <input type="text" name="last_name">
        Email: <input type="text" name="email">
        <input type="submit">
</form>
```

My database has: `id, first_name, last_name, email`

Thanks so much. I'm a beginner so any help is appreciated!

Update:Answered! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Change the INSERT query to:

```
INSERT INTO users (first_name, last_name, email) VALUES (       
'{$_POST[first_name]}', '{$_POST[last_name]}', '{$_POST[email]}')
```

Note: using `_` as ID doesn't sound like a good practice. But more important, I'd like to introduce my friend *[Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/)*

Comment: Thanks for responding -- this eliminated the error message, but it's not inserting the fields into my database. Any other thoughts?

Comment: How is `ID` column defined in your DB ? Number ?

Comment: id: int(11), not-null, auto_increment

Comment: That means you can't pass `_` as id in the insert (MySQL auto-generates and inserts the IDs for you). Just remove the 'ID' part from the insert - see updated answer.

Comment: Still no luck unfortunately. How should I define the id in the database other than int?

Comment: This shows you did not define your table and its key well

Comment: Start debugging then, echo the values of `$_POST[first_name]`, `$_POST[last_name]` and `email`. Also, post the full description of the table `users`

Answer (score 0):

Use this code,this might help

```
<?php

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","***","***") or die ("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("****");

$sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (first_name, last_name, email) VALUES (       
'{$_POST[first_name]}', '{$_POST[last_name]}', '{$_POST[email]}')") or die ('Error     updating   
database: '.mysql_error());

?>
```

Comment: Awesome! That worked! Forgot the mysql_query part. Thank you!